# choosing a percentage of a dataset

Tags: matlab, octave

I am new to matlab and I cant find anything in the documentation for this, I have a method of sampling a dataset but I was wondering rather than using direct numbers how I can use a percentage:

```
normIdx = strmatch('normal.', TestDataLabels);
normalSubset = Testdata(normIdx, :);
normal = randperm(size(normalSubset , 1));
p = (normal(1:10000))'; % here I choose 10000 samples but I would like to use a percentage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
pcnt = 75; % The percent of original data set size you wish your sample size to be
sampleN = ceil( (pcnt/100) * length(normal) ); % figure out what pcnt percent of original N is, and round upward

p = normal(1:sampleN)';
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont follow what you mean when you say 'how do you keep the indices?' And you bet, I'm glad to help! ;)

Comment: Ah never mind jerad p is my indices, sorry another late night for me!